# Python Pop() function

Tags: python

I'm a programming student and am learning python.

I wanted to ask how I would use the pop() function to remove and eventually return a column in the below code? I tried but it keeps removing a row instead? Also I'm not allowed to use pandas. I would like to remove the Country column.

My code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to load dataset from a file
def load_datalist(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            rows = file.readlines()
            headers = rows[0].strip().split(',')
            values = [row.strip().split(',') for row in rows[1:]]
#Dictionary for countries
            country = values[0]
            data_dict={}
            for i in range (1,len(values)):
              data= values.pop(0)
              print(data)
              
            return headers, values, data
    except IOError:
        print("An error occurred reading the file")
        return None, None
```

Data set:

```
Country,Attending events,Care for household members,Eating and drinking,Education,Housework,Other leisure activities,Other unpaid work & volunteering,Paid work,Personal care,Seeing friends,Shopping,Sleep,Sports,TV and Radio
Australia,6,45,89,27,132,76,58,211,56,40,29,512,19,140
Austria,9,34,79,27,125,59,32,280,55,82,21,498,32,109
Belgium,15,22,99,41,121,122,30,194,53,50,29,513,21,131
Canada,6,29,65,36,115,89,52,269,52,53,24,520,21,109
China,2,23,100,25,103,53,33,315,52,23,20,542,23,127
Denmark,7,28,119,25,128,95,45,200,52,81,26,489,22,123
Estonia,8,28,79,25,121,114,40,231,54,38,24,530,27,122
Finland,8,23,81,29,109,113,81,200,52,55,26,508,37,118
France,15,22,133,34,129,98,17,170,107,55,22,513,12,114
Germany,14,19,95,24,109,112,53,224,55,61,32,498,26,118
Greece,5,19,128,40,125,115,26,187,57,56,16,500,28,137
Hungary,6,33,101,38,150,94,36,199,76,35,19,506,13,134
India,5,21,84,23,148,109,22,272,75,73,12,528,5,61
Ireland,42,61,75,37,91,116,72,231,42,49,28,491,20,85
Italy,6,27,127,28,135,110,43,149,68,65,28,513,38,104
Korea,4,28,117,57,76,82,42,288,90,42,13,471,27,102
Latvia,5,15,89,13,130,81,39,317,40,35,16,512,25,123
Lithuania,1,19,88,12,154,61,42,304,54,32,17,503,16,137
Luxembourg,12,20,112,37,108,82,42,247,55,32,23,518,33,116
Mexico,7,38,77,45,187,41,46,302,58,44,14,499,14,66
Netherlands,7,22,114,25,105,101,46,218,65,73,28,503,22,113
New Zealand,6,30,80,29,110,85,59,241,42,69,24,526,17,124
Norway,8,23,79,40,83,154,77,201,56,57,20,492,21,129
Poland,3,38,91,30,135,93,39,229,57,45,25,509,23,122
Portugal,11,17,112,36,161,60,35,259,58,44,15,506,12,114
Slovenia,5,21,86,38,166,92,32,227,41,62,18,501,32,120
South Africa,5,18,72,39,130,82,41,189,70,82,9,553,5,132
Spain,9,35,126,26,116,85,54,176,51,51,25,516,42,129
Sweden,9,33,83,31,107,112,33,262,57,53,23,483,34,113
Turkey,3,29,118,29,124,82,60,217,50,68,14,515,9,124
UK,7,32,79,27,104,98,62,235,58,47,29,508,19,133
USA,8,31,63,31,100,73,65,251,57,44,22,528,18,148`
```

This is the result when I run my code:

```
'Austria', '9', '34', '79', '27', '125', '59', '32', '280', '55', '82', '21', '498', '32', '109']
['Belgium', '15', '22', '99', '41', '121', '122', '30', '194', '53', '50', '29', '513', '21', '131']
['Canada', '6', '29', '65', '36', '115', '89', '52', '269', '52', '53', '24', '520', '21', '109']
['China', '2', '23', '100', '25', '103', '53', '33', '315', '52', '23', '20', '542', '23', '127']
['Denmark', '7', '28', '119', '25', '128', '95', '45', '200', '52', '81', '26', '489', '22', '123']
['Estonia', '8', '28', '79', '25', '121', '114', '40', '231', '54', '38', '24', '530', '27', '122']
['Finland', '8', '23', '81', '29', '109', '113', '81', '200', '52', '55', '26', '508', '37', '118']
['France', '15', '22', '133', '34', '129', '98', '17', '170', '107', '55', '22', '513', '12', '114']
['Germany', '14', '19', '95', '24', '109', '112', '53', '224', '55', '61', '32', '498', '26', '118']
['Greece', '5', '19', '128', '40', '125', '115', '26', '187', '57', '56', '16', '500', '28', '137']
['Hungary', '6', '33', '101', '38', '150', '94', '36', '199', '76', '35', '19', '506', '13', '134']
['India', '5', '21', '84', '23', '148', '109', '22', '272', '75', '73', '12', '528', '5', '61']
['Ireland', '42', '61', '75', '37', '91', '116', '72', '231', '42', '49', '28', '491', '20', '85']
['Italy', '6', '27', '127', '28', '135', '110', '43', '149', '68', '65', '28', '513', '38', '104']
['Korea', '4', '28', '117', '57', '76', '82', '42', '288', '90', '42', '13', '471', '27', '102']
['Latvia', '5', '15', '89', '13', '130', '81', '39', '317', '40', '35', '16', '512', '25', '123']
['Lithuania', '1', '19', '88', '12', '154', '61', '42', '304', '54', '32', '17', '503', '16', '137']
['Luxembourg', '12', '20', '112', '37', '108', '82', '42', '247', '55', '32', '23', '518', '33', '116']
['Mexico', '7', '38', '77', '45', '187', '41', '46', '302', '58', '44', '14', '499', '14', '66']
['Netherlands', '7', '22', '114', '25', '105', '101', '46', '218', '65', '73', '28', '503', '22', '113']
['New Zealand', '6', '30', '80', '29', '110', '85', '59', '241', '42', '69', '24', '526', '17', '124']
['Norway', '8', '23', '79', '40', '83', '154', '77', '201', '56', '57', '20', '492', '21', '129']
['Poland', '3', '38', '91', '30', '135', '93', '39', '229', '57', '45', '25', '509', '23', '122']
['Portugal', '11', '17', '112', '36', '161', '60', '35', '259', '58', '44', '15', '506', '12', '114']
['Slovenia', '5', '21', '86', '38', '166', '92', '32', '227', '41', '62', '18', '501', '32', '120']
['South Africa', '5', '18', '72', '39', '130', '82', '41', '189', '70', '82', '9', '553', '5', '132']
['Spain', '9', '35', '126', '26', '116', '85', '54', '176', '51', '51', '25', '516', '42', '129']
['Sweden', '9', '33', '83', '31', '107', '112', '33', '262', '57', '53', '23', '483', '34', '113']
['Turkey', '3', '29', '118', '29', '124', '82', '60', '217', '50', '68', '14', '515', '9', '124']
['UK', '7', '32', '79', '27', '104', '98', '62', '235', '58', '47', '29', '508', '19', '133']
['USA', '8', '31', '63', '31', '100', '73', '65', '251', '57', '44', '22', '528', '18', '148']
```

Comment: I have to remove the country column

Comment: Are you ok with using Pandas?

Comment: Or, if not Pandas, have a look at the built-in [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Both may make your life/code easier.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not allowed to use pandas in the assignment

Comment: Store all your data in a dict of lists, then once done reading the file, removing the "Country" key.

Comment: Can you show me how you would code it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to load dataset from a file
def load_datalist(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            rows = file.readlines()
            headers = rows[0].strip().split(',')
            headers.remove("Country")
            values = [row.strip().split(',') for row in rows[1:]]
#Dictionary for countries
            countries = []
            for i in range(0,len(values)):
              countries.append(values[i].pop(0))
              print(countries[i-1])
              
            return headers, values, countries
    except IOError:
        print("An error occurred reading the file")
        return None, None
    
print(load_datalist('rd.csv'))
```

The three return values  1)`headers` contain column names except `Country` column 2)`values` contains values of all columns except `Country` column  and 3)`countries` contains the values of `Countries` column

`split()` function returns a list so your values list is a list of lists or a 2d list.So you have to use `values[index].pop(0)` to remove country names from each row.

Comment: How would I do this with a matrix? eg matrix  =[[1,2,3],
                      [4,5,6],
                      [7,8,9]]

Comment: can you please clearly explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to be able to make a dictionary out of the above dataset e.g. Australia:{'Attending Events':6, 'Care for household members':45, 'Eating and drinking':89} etc

Comment: But I can't use numpy or pandas

Comment: make a dictionary `data = {}`. while iterating  through the values list  assign `data[values[i][0]] = {headers[1]:values[i][1],headers[2]:values[i][2]}` and so on